# How to replace specified word of the Latin in other specified word using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to replace some word with another over javascript.

I find some code which I tried:

```
<script>
$string = str_replace(
array('š', 'č', 'đ', 'ć', 'ž'),  
array('s', 'c', 'dj', 'c', 'z'),
$string);
</script>
```

but I don't know coding and when I put this on the website I got the error in console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: you are getting this error because u have not loaded the jquery

Comment: ^^^ Also `str_replace` is not a native javascript method.  There is a php method by that name.  So unless you have a definitiion for that method yourself, that's also an issue

Comment: use this function to replace the strings
var str = "Visit Microsoft!";
var res = str.replace("Microsoft", "W3Schools");

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It sounds like you have a bit of learning ahead of you. There are plenty of resources out there such as Free Code Camp (which I recommend if you are serious about learning to code)

Answer (score 0):

you are getting this error because u have not loaded the jquery To tackle this situation open the below link copy the code and paste it into your console.
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: Now i get this error Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined?

Comment: use without the <script> tag.

Answer (score 0):

codes you use in php code

```html
<?php
$text = "99skdlsakd sakdlşsakşđđđd klşsaćkd lşds asldklş sadw";
$search = array('š', 'č', 'đ', 'ć', 'ž');
$replace = array('s', 'c', 'dj', 'c', 'z');
$string = str_replace($search, $replace, $text);
echo $string;
?>
```

Comment: he is asking for the jquery or javascript code to be placed in the console not for the php code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = 'ščđ';

var mapObj = {
   š:"s",
   đ:"dj",
   č:"c"
};
str = str.replace(/š|đ|č/gi, function(matched){
  return mapObj[matched];
});

console.log(str);
```